# Placement New and Perfect Forwarding

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code that intends to create an array, but without default initialization of its objects. I would like to forward perfectly to placement new, which seems to happen, but I find that the objects' destructor is called inside the emplace function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // std::uninitialized_copy, std::allocator...
#include <utility> // std::move...
#include <bitset>


struct Int {

    int i;

    Int ( ) : i ( -1 ) { std::cout << "default constructed\n"; }
    Int ( const int i_ ) : i ( i_ ) { std::cout << i << " constructed\n"; }
    Int ( Int && int_ ) : i ( std::move ( int_.i ) ) { std::cout << i << " move constructed\n"; }
    Int ( const Int & int_ ) : i ( int_.i ) { std::cout << i << " copy constructed\n"; }
    ~Int ( ) { std::cout << i << " destructed\n"; i = -1; }
};


template <typename T, size_t S = 64>
class NoInitArray {

    std::bitset<S> m_used;

    T *m_array = reinterpret_cast < T* > ( ::operator new ( sizeof ( T ) * S ) );

public:

    T const &operator [ ] ( const size_t idx_ ) const {

        return m_array [ idx_ ];
    }

    NoInitArray ( ) { }

    ~NoInitArray ( ) {

        for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < S; ++idx ) {

            if ( m_used [ idx ] ) {

                reinterpret_cast< const T* > ( m_array + idx )->~T ( );
            }
        }
    }

    template<typename ...Args>
    void emplace ( const size_t idx_, Args &&... value_ ) {

        std::cout << "start emplace\n";

        m_used [ idx_ ] = 1;

        new ( m_array + idx_ ) T ( std::forward<T> ( value_ ) ... );

        std::cout << "end emplace\n";
    }
};


int main ( ) {

    NoInitArray<Int> nia;

    nia.emplace ( 0, 0 );
    nia.emplace ( 1, 1 );

    std::cout << nia [ 1 ].i << std::endl;

    nia.emplace ( 2, 2 );

    return 0;
}
```

The result of running this program is as follows:

```
start emplace
0 constructed
0 move constructed
0 destructed
end emplace
start emplace
1 constructed
1 move constructed
1 destructed
end emplace
1
start emplace
2 constructed
2 move constructed
2 destructed
end emplace
0 destructed
1 destructed
2 destructed
```

It shows that the objects are constructed once and destructed twice (which obviously is UB), once inside the emplace function, and then once at destruction of the NoInitArray.

The question is "Why is the destructor of my Int object called inside the emplace function"?

Compiler, latest Clang/LLVM on Windhoze.

EDIT1: I've added move and copy constructors to the Int struct, now the count matches, i.e. 2 constructions and 2 destructions.

EDIT2: Changing the Placement New line from `new ( m_array + idx_ ) T ( std::forward<T> ( value_ ) ... );` to `new ( m_array + idx_ ) T ( value_ ... );` avoids the superfluous construction/destruction, without the need for a move constructor.

EDIT3: Just for future readers. As per above, the ~NoInitArray() leaks memory. Calling delete on m_array is bad news as well as this calls (in Clang/LLVM) the destructor of m_array [ 0 ] (but as far as I've understood now, that is in no way guaranteed, i.e. UB). std::malloc/std::free seems to be the way to go, but some say that if you do that all hell will break lose, and one may lose a leg.

Comment: Be sure to also count copy constructor calls.

Comment: @BenVoigt Doesn't the copy constructor call the ordinary constructor? If this is the problem, that this means the forwarding doesn't work as intended, how can I then make this work, i.e. move the object instead of copying it?

Comment: No, copy construction doesn't chain to the default constructor.  If you're expecting moves and not copies, provide user-defined version of both move and copy constructor and log distinct messages in each.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've edited the question, adding your suggestions. But I see (now) 2 con/destructions. How can I get rid of one of them, if at all possible?

Comment: @BenVoigt I've got it thanks to your suggestions. Taking out the std::forward in the Placement New got rid of the copying. Thank you for joggling my grey matter.

Comment: @ChristopherOicles I was of course aware of that, but thanks for your second suggestion...

Comment: In case it's not already there, in your real code, make sure emplace checks m_used[ idx_ ] for an existing constructed object, and if so call m_array[idx_].~T() before doing placement new.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you accounted for that (I removed the assignment suggestion because it would be inappropriate there, because emplace will pass on multiple arguments to the constructor, but an assignment just expects one argument).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It shows that the objects are constructed once and destructed twice" is not true. The output `X move constructed` should be included as one construction so the constructions are twice.

The line

```
new ( m_array + idx_ ) T ( std::forward<T> ( value_ ) ... );
```

should be

```
new ( m_array + idx_ ) T ( std::forward<Args&&> ( value_ )... );
```

`std::forward<T>(value_)` calls the constructor when `T=Int`, and this temporary object is moved, so there is an extra move constructor call.

EDIT

In your edit 2 you replace the line without `std::forward` anymore. In this case, OK, but the differences emerge when you call the `emplace` like this

```
    nia.emplace ( 0, Int(0) );
```

Without `std::forward`, `new T(value_...)` would call the copy constructor, while `new T(std::forward<Args&&>(value_)...)` would call the move constructor.

EDIT-2

It should be `new T(std::forward<Args>(value_)...)`. Thanks to @Constantin Baranov.

Comment: Thanks for this, as indicated in my EDIT2, in this case it also work as I describe there. Is this (my) way of doing it correct or is it in a non-trivial case (unlike this one) obligatory to use your solution? The result seems to be the same, there's no call to the move constructor, AFAICS.

Comment: @degski Updated my post. I also suggest go finding more details about `std::forward` in other questions or websites.

Comment: Tricky stuff, the quote "... but with c++ you can blow your leg of ..." comes to mind. With c++11 it seems you can blow both legs of. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to pick your brain again and a bit more, but referring to what you write in your edit, I have an additional question. Why would you call emplace like that?

Comment: It should be `std::forward<Args>(value_)`. Fortunately, extra `&&` doesn't make things worse, as far as I can see.

Comment: @ConstantinBaranov Yes you are right. The return type of `forward` contains an `&&` so it was unnecessary. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @degski Just an example to tell the difference.

Comment: Your first edit is somewhat misleading, because you're talking about copy and move construction of the `value...` objects, not any `T` object.

Answer (score 4):

I think the constructor and destructor are called in the step: `std::forward<T> ( value_ )` in  `new ( m_array + idx_ ) T ( std::forward<T> ( value_ ) ... )`.

The `std::forward<T>(value_)` will create a temp value T.

Comment: I can only accept one answer, neuront's answer is slightly more complete, so I accepted his, thanks for yours.